# Why doesn't this code save my figures with titles?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm producing some figures with the following code:

```
def boxplot_data(self,parameters_file,figure_title):
    data = pandas.read_csv(parameters_file)
    header = data.keys()
    number_of_full_subplots = len(header)/16
    remainder = len(header)-(16*number_of_full_subplots)
    try:
        for i in range(number_of_full_subplots+1):
            fig =plt.figure(i)
            txt = fig.suptitle(figure_title+' (n='+str(len(data[header[0]]))+') '+'Page '+str(i)+' of '+str(number_of_full_subplots),fontsize='20')
            txt.set_text(figure_title+' (n='+str(len(data[header[0]]))+') '+'Page '+str(i)+' of '+str(number_of_full_subplots))
            for j in range(16):
                plt.ioff()
                plt.subplot(4,4,j)
                plt.boxplot(data[header[16*i+j]])
                plt.xlabel('')  
                mng=plt.get_current_fig_manager()
                mng.window.showMaximized()                    
                plt.savefig(str(i)+'.png',bbox_inches='tight',orientation='landscape')
                plt.close(fig)                    
                plt.ion()
    except IndexError:
        txt = fig.suptitle(figure_title+' (n='+str(len(data[header[0]]))+') '+'Page '+str(i)+' of '+str(number_of_full_subplots),fontsize='20')
        txt.set_text(figure_title+' (n='+str(len(data[header[0]]))+') '+'Page '+str(i)+' of '+str(number_of_full_subplots))
        print '{} full figures were created and 1 partially filled \
        figure containing {} subplots'.format(number_of_full_subplots,remainder)
```

This produces and saves the figures to file in the properly formatted manner however, no matter what I do the code seems to bypass the fig.suptitle line(s) and consequently I can't give my figure a title. Apologies if it seems there is a lot going on in this function that I haven't explained but does anybody have an explanation as to why this code refuses to give my figures titles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not that `suptitle` is bypassed, but that you are never saving the figure that you call `suptitle` on.  All your calls to `savefig` are within the inner loop and as such are saving only the subplots.  You can actually watch this happening if you open the `png` file while your code is running - you see each of the 16 sub axes being added one by one.

Your code looks unnecessarily complicated.  For instance, I don't think you need to use `ion` and `ioff`. Here is a simple example of how to do what I think you want, followed by a translation of your code to fit that (Obviously i can't test, because I don't have your data)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
test_y=range(10)
test_x=[8,13,59,8,81,2,5,6,2,3]

def subplotsave_test():
    for i in range(5):
        fig = plt.figure(i)
        txt = fig.suptitle('Page '+str(i)+' of '+str(5),fontsize='20')
        for j in range(16):
            plt.subplot(4,4,j+1)
            plt.plot(test_y,test_x)          
        plt.savefig(str(i)+'.png',bbox_inches='tight',orientation='landscape')
                
if __name__ == '__main__':                
    subplotsave_test()
```

One tip I have found works for me - do a `plt.show()` wherever you intend to save the figure and ensure it looks like you want beforehanad and then ***replace*** that call with `plt.savefig()`

#### Possible translation of your function

```
def boxplot_data(self,parameters_file,figure_title):
    data = pandas.read_csv(parameters_file)
    header = data.keys()
    number_of_full_subplots = len(header)/16
    remainder = len(header)-(16*number_of_full_subplots)
    for i in range(number_of_full_subplots+1)
        fig =plt.figure(i)
        fig.suptitle(figure_title+' (n='+str(len(data[header[0]]))+') '+'Page '+str(i)+' of '+str(number_of_full_subplots),fontsize='20')
        for j in range(16):
            plt.subplot(4,4,j+1)
            if 16*i + j < len(header):
                plt.boxplot(data[header[16*i+j]])
                plt.xlabel('')    
                #You might want the showMaximized() call here - does nothing
                #on my machine but YMMV
            else:
                print '{} full figures were created and 1 partially filled \
                figure containing {} subplots'.format(number_of_full_subplots,remainder)
                break                
        plt.savefig(str(i)+'.png',bbox_inches='tight',orientation='landscape')
        plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: Your code not only works but is about 10 times more efficient than mine. Thank you

Comment: No problem - glad it helped :)